# Cannot change style of an array element with onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with following code (it just wont change the top attribute :s)

```
var selectedDivs = new Array();

function addBorder(e) {
      if ($ctrlBeingpressed == true) {
      e.target.style.border="5px solid green"; // to show they are selected
      selectedDivs.push(e.target);
      }
  }

  function test(){
  alert('changing position');
   selectedDivs[0].style.top="10px";
  }


<button type="button" onclick="test()">Right</button>
```

Some generated HTML (addBorder is called in Onclick on one of the DIV's here):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head> … </head>
    <body style="position: absolute; cursor: auto;" application"="" onkeyup="clearPress()> <div id=" onkeydown="controlCheck(event)">
        <div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:300px;height:900px" role="tablist"> … </div>
        <div id="buttons" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:315px;width:1100px;height:50px;border:2px solid grey"> … </div>
        <div id="canvas" class="DROPPABLE ui-droppable" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:315px;width:1100px;height:850px;border:2px solid grey">
            <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-widget-content ui-draggable" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 120px; height: 60px; top: 156.117px; left: 188.117px; position: relative;" onclick="addBorder(event)">
                <img id="PMF00" src="/devices/AAU01-010.gif" style="border: 5px solid green;"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-widget-content ui-draggable" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 120px; height: 60px; top: 10px; left: 10px; position: relative;" onclick="addBorder(event)">
                <img id="PMF01" src="/devices/AAU01-010.gif"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: looks like you have other elements placed on top of the button http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZUTNg/1/

Comment: Instead of using onclick="addBorder(event)" i used onclick="addBorder(this)",
making sure that i wasnt change the style of the image, which is what was happening here. 
(Because the image was in the div, ofcoures it wouldnt move)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure is

```
$ctrlBeingpressed
```

is set and is it true ?

Otherwise this

```
selectedDivs.push(e.target);
```

wont executed and your

```
selectedDivs[0]
```

will be undefined

Comment: Instead of using onclick="addBorder(event)" i used onclick="addBorder(this)",
making sure that i wasnt change the style of the image, which is what was happening here. 
(Because the image was in the div, ofcoures it wouldnt move)